# Is there any alternate of ngrok?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, localhost, ngrok

Actually i am trying to run my localhost react application on my android mobile. And for this purpose I am using **ngrok**. But with it after some time latter it is throwing an error of **ERR_NGROK_702**.

[image]

If Any one has solution for running localhost react application on my Android mobile from Linux Os. Then Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try to the [httpdumper npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpdumper)

More info here: https://dev.to/merlier/how-to-test-your-local-website-on-real-phone-devices-2o11

Comment: I have checked this httpdumper module but it is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

***https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel*** should help.

if you want self hosted alternative you can use ***https://github.com/mmatczuk/go-http-tunnel***.